# Comparing part of a string

Tags: delphi

I got a problem with Delphi.

I have to compare a string of 4 char, with data in database which is 6 char long (postal code(netherlands)).

What I have now is:

```
procedure Tfmpostcode.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  postcode : string;
  target: string;
begin
 postcode := ePostcode.text;
 target :=  leftStr(postcode,4);
 dm.atinlog.filter   := 'postcode ='  + (target);
 dm.atinlog.filtered := true;
 dbgrid1.visible := true;
end;
```

I have been searching the net, and I found you could use ansistring. but it gives an error.

> missing operator or semicolon

What should I do?

**I updated the code**

***Additional info:***

I need to compare a part of the string with data in database
If i enter 5504BX in edit field
the dbgrid should show up with
5504LA
5504KJ
all that starts with the first 4 numbers. the letters doesnt matter.

Comment: Besides the local declaration of "AnsileftStr", what about the brackets around "(target)"? It may also be possible that the filter needs quoting the string.

Comment: @Uwe: Putting parenthesis around a string shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: @uwe I have used the filter before, but never where i need a part of a string, that is the problem right here, the local decleration is fixed that was stupid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to quote the string. Use QuotedStr.

```
dm.atinlog.filter   := 'postcode = '  + QuotedStr(target);
```

If you need a wild-card match you can do

```
dm.atinlog.filter   := 'postcode like '  + QuotedStr(target+'%');
```

Comment: You sir, have my thanks! that like did it. Didn't know there was something like that.. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also just use `PostCode=' + QuotedStr(Target + '*');` provided you don't add foNoPartialCompare to dm.atinlog.FilterOptions - see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TFilterOptions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function LeftStr from StrUtils.pas

```
function LeftStr(const AText: AnsiString; const ACount: Integer): AnsiString; overload;
function LeftStr(const AText: WideString; const ACount: Integer): WideString; overload;
```

or

```
function AnsiLeftStr(const AText: string; const ACount: Integer): string; overload;
```

But don't declare it as a variable.

Try:

```
procedure Tfmpostcode.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  postcode : string;
  target   : string;
begin
 postcode := ePostcode.text;
 target   := LeftStr(postcode, 4);  
 //...
end;
```

But, because the postalcode is entered from within a edit box. You probably need some safeguards (only accept alphanumeric chars) or use Trim(ePostcode.text) to delete extra spaces. And if you want to get the last part, don't forget that some people add a space between the number and the letters (1234 AB).

Comment: Ok I changed that, i left the variable out. And i declared it in uses. That works fine now. however it seems i won't find anything anymore. Probably doing something wrong. In my database there is an postal code of 5504LA, if there is more data with 5504XX it should show up. I need to filter it on the first 4 char. I am doing it right like this right?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give a line associated with the error, but if I had to guess, I'd say it's complaining about the line that says

```
target :=  AnsileftStr(postcode,4);
```

You declared AnsileftStr as a variable, then you're trying to use it with syntax that looks like a function call with two arguments.  Are you trying to call the `AnsiLeftStr` function from the `StrUtils` unit?  If so, your code would probably work fine if you removed the variable declaration and made sure that `StrUtils` is in your **uses** clause.

Comment: that was indeed the correct line, I put the strutils in uses, that's 1 thing. But still it's not working.